# What is OpenGL Default Light Position?

Tags: opengl, light, directional-light

i want to learn about default light positions in opengl.

i have a system setted up like; if there is no light in the scene, system adds a environment light in the scene :

```
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);
Gl.glLightf(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 99999);
```

if i dont touch the light's Position parameter, light is like an environment light, it doesnt seem like it has a direction, so my objects get light from every angles.. thats kind of cool.. but if i do that:

```
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);
Gl.glLightf(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 99999);
Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_POSITION, new Vector4(0f, 0f, 1f, 0f).ToArray());
```

(which is the original value already, because i tested it with Gl.glGetLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_POSITION, vec); and it is the same). after i mess with position, it realy becomes like a directional sun light, but i want it to work it like enviroment light. waht am i missing here?

Comment: i am trying that right now thanks

Comment: nope, if i set zero all the values for diffuse, i get one color scene, no lighting.. again i realy dont understand why when i set the position vaue it messes default lighting results.. i mean i am setting the same position value already

Comment: ok  i think the problem is about my external opengl get set methods.. because i set light position with 0,0,1,0 and when i try to get it i get weird values... i am using Tao.OpenGl and i didnt have any problem like that other then the light position..

Comment: i think i have to open another question for this issue because, i tested the code above, it's not about light..

    float[] position = new float[4]; //position:0,0,0,0

    Gl.glGetLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_POSITION, position);//position:0,0,1,0

    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_POSITION, position);

    Gl.glGetLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_POSITION, position);//position:1.94068335E-07  0.821321964  0.570465  0

Comment: `glLightfv(..., GL_POSITION, ...)` will transform the position vector _by the current modelView matrix_ to get the eye space light position which is finally stored in the GL state. However, all of this is moot, since this stuff is deprecated since a decade now.